# -z option inside if condition in shell script

Tags: shell, scripting

Can someone post me the significance of -z option while writing if condition using shell scripts.

Let me paste the exact condition what I am looking at

```
if [[ "x$do_clean_flag" = "x-clean" && -z "$show_me_flag" && "$verify" = true ]]
```

Answer (score 70, accepted):

From "help test":

```
-z STRING      True if string is empty.
```

Comment: +1 - Also returns true when testing an uninitialised variable

Comment: Thanks! It helped me a lot.

Answer (score 8):

-z checks whether $show_me_flag is defined

check out the manual of test([1](http://ss64.com/bash/test.html))

Answer (score 4):

-z (something) means if (something) is NULL then return true

http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?test

suggests that zero length returns true as well, I'd suggest doing "man test" on your machine to check the exact wording on your system.

Comment: No. `-z NULL` returns **false**. -z justs tests if the string is empty. So `-z ""` returns true.

Comment: On my Ubuntu system I see: test -z NULL ; echo $?  returns 1. test -z "" ; echo $?  returns 0. test -z "something" ; echo $?  returns 1. So zero length returns false, I was wrong about that, but NULL returns true.

Comment: Actually, my OSX system gives the same output as you for those commands. But my man test says `The test utility evaluates the expression and, if it evaluates to true, returns a zero (true) exit status; otherwise it returns 1 (false). If there is no expression, test also returns 1 (false).` **So, 1 means false, and 0 means true, here.** Further it states that: `-z string     True if the length of string is zero.`